# Associate file type to external program in WiX

Tags: wix

Is there a way to associate a file extension to an external program in my WiX setup?

For example, my application uses .xyz files, but I use a third party program to edit them, like Notepad++. I would include Notepad++ during the setup or bootstrap its installer. Is there a way to associate Notepad++ with my .xyz files using only WiX?

I've looked at the `ProgId` element, but I don't think it can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the strongly typed elements cannot be used to refer to an executable outside of the install today. However, you can write the registry keys yourself. Something like:

```
<RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key=".xyz" Value="xyz-progid" Type="string" />
<RegistryKey Root="HCKR" Key="xyz-progid>
   <RegistryValue Key="shell\Open\command" Value="[NOTEPADPLUSPLUSPATH]" Type="string" />
   <RegistryValue Key="DefaultIcon" Value="[!NOTEPADPLUSPLUSPATH]" Type="string" />
</RegistryKey>
```

For this to work, you'll need to find Notepad++ on the machine. I'm not sure how to do that but let's say there was a registry key that told you:

```
<Property Id="NOTEPADPLUSPLUSPATH">
    <RegistrySearch Id="FindNotepadPlusPlus" Root="HKLM" Key="Software\NotepadPlusPlus"
                    Name="InstallPath" Type="raw" />
</Property>
```

Comment: Thanks! As an aside, would a compiler extension be able to do what I want?

Comment: You could wrap those elements up in a compiler extension but it'd end up being the exact same thing in the end.